# How do you include a non-referenced dll when publishing a web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I have various dll's that I am not directly referencing in a ASP.NET website I am attempting to publish via the "Package/Publish Web" feature in Visual Studio 2010.

**How can I tell the publishing feature that it needs to include these certain files?**

Note that I do not want to directly reference these dll's (the solution has specifically been setup in a way so that these specific dll's are not directly referenced).

I've found a `<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment/>` but I can't find a way to specifically include files.

Comment: Why are you opposed to just referencing the DLLs?

Comment: If the dll's are referenced, the programmer could use those classes in those dll's directly, rather than use the abstraction layers I have set up. More concretely, I have interfaces in one project (which is referenced), and the concrete implementation in another project (which is not referenced). This is all hooked together via a DI container, and a simple config file entry hooks everything up. I don't want the programmer bypassing this infrastructure.

Comment: Yes Oded, in a perfect world, these violations would be picked up by nDepend. It is not that I don't trust the developers (of which I am very much included), it is that I would like to lead them to the "pit of success". If I can simplify project references so that the team can't easily get themselves in trouble, then that is a win. On a team with varied experience levels across many projects, across multiple platforms, any win is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include files through the Publish method you could use "FilesForPackagingFromProject" elements in the MSbuild file (.*proj)

Usefull link : http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can add them to the project (just like you add an image) and change the property *Copy To Output Directory* to *Copy if Newer*.  Then when you build they should be placed into the bin.  That should work when you publish too.

Comment: This is certainly an option, even if it is a bit of a hack. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah.  We had a solution similar to what you are doing when we used Unity, and I feel your pain. We used post build events to push the dll's into the bin, but when publishing we had to remember to go grab them manually.

Answer (score 1):

It will only publish from the folders in your website.  I have always just had the website reference those files so when I built it they were then local to the site and would be published along with everything else.

Comment: There is a visual studio plugin that will do what you want.  http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/VisualStudio/126_Web_Deployment_Project_for_Visual_Studio_2005_and_2008.aspx

Comment: vs 2010 version too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx

Comment: Thanks phillip - I'll check out those links.